# Redux state return empty state alternatively

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I am getting `filteredStudents` state empty array alternatively even when clicking on a section, it returns an array of students but when I click on a different section, it returns an empty array. When I click again on the same section its value is updated. Is there any fix for this?

```
let filteredStudents=state.?filteredStudentsReducer?.filteredStudents 


// dispatching action from main js value: {section: "A" } students:[{name:"a", division:"A" }, ] I am passing values similar to these.
dispatch({
    type: "FILTER_STUDENTS_SECTION",
    value: obj,
    students: students,
  });

 // this is the reducer , to filter students based on section

 case "FILTER_STUDENTS_SECTION":

  //filter students based on section
  let obj1 = action.value;
  let stds1;

  if (state.filteredStudents.length) {
    stds1 = state.filteredStudents.filter((s) => {
      return s.division === obj1.section;
    });
  } else {
    stds1 = action?.students;
    stds1 = stds1.filter((s) => {
      return s.division === obj1.section;
    });
  }



  return {
    ...state,
    filteredStudents: stds1,
    message: "Students filtered section wise",
    loading: false,
  };
```

Comment: from your comment, I understand that your students array contains objects having the `section` property, but when you filter them, you use the `division` property which does not exist. Just try `s.section === action.value.section` in the filter callback

Comment: Also, you shouldn't use the `filteredStudents` from the state, but always filter all the students to get the desired results. IMO, this statement `if (state.filteredStudents.length) {` should be removed completely

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sorry for the confusion. I have edited the question. I have passing value obj: { section: "A"} and students has { name:"A", divison: "A"} property.  I am using 
if(state.filteredStudents.length) {} because I am filtering students based on section as well. So if there is filteredStudnets it should filter based on the section too.

Comment: Filtering like that should be done in a selector, not in a copy of state in your state. See https://redux.js.org/recipes/computing-derived-data

Comment: I have tried to update it using local state but it still gives me same result . Using selectors could not resolve the issue

Comment: I was able to solve by changing filtered students state to local react instead of redux. It seems there was some mismatch